# Phonegap CLI Build fail

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I'm getting some errors trying to build a project using the Phonegap CLI. If I try to use the build service I get an error stating that /Local/Temp/marker.js_(somehash) is Busy or Locked.

I can go in and clear out all the marker.js files but still get the error.

If I try to build locally I get an error stating no such file or directory .cordova\hooks\before_platform_add

I followed the docs to install the CLI and install phonegap but it seems like I'm missing something? Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: 3.0, but I think that's the problem. Some of the docs that come up are for edge, some were for 3.0. It seems a lot of documentation out there calls for cordova commands, and some for phonegap. I'm trying to sort through them all. I was able to get it to work on my Mac but no my Win8 machine.